# AutoMapper com Expression

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo um repositório genérico e me deparei com a seguinte situação.

Nesta chamada consigo fazer o mapeamento e funciona perfeito.

```
    public IEnumerable<PaisViewModel> GetAll()
    {
        return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Pais>, IEnumerable<PaisViewModel>>(_paisService.GetAll());
    }
```

Mas neste caso estou tendo dificuldades pois utiliza expression. Sendo que minha entidade é Pais e utilizo a ViewModelPais. Como faço automapper com expression?

```
    public IEnumerable<PaisViewModel> Find(Expression<Func<PaisViewModel, bool>> predicate)
    {
       return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Pais>, IEnumerable<PaisViewModel>>(_paisService.Find(predicate));
    }
```

Esse projeto segue esta arquitetura

http://eduardopires.net.br/2014/10/tutorial-asp-net-mvc-5-ddd-ef-automapper-ioc-dicas-e-truques/

Sou iniciante no C# me deparei com esta situação onde tenho que implementar estes CRUD genéricos.

**Camada de Domínio**

```
namespace Sistema.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Pais
    {
        public int PaisId { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Camada de Servico**

```
namespace Sistema.Domain.Interfaces.Services
{
    public interface IServiceBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
        TEntity GetById(object id);
        IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
        void Add(TEntity entity);
        void Update(TEntity entity);
        void Remove(TEntity entity);
    }
}

namespace Sistema.Domain.Services
{
    public class ServiceBase<TEntity> : IDisposable, IServiceBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {

        private readonly IRepositoryBase<TEntity> _repository;

        public ServiceBase(IRepositoryBase<TEntity> repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return _repository.GetAll();
        }

        public TEntity GetById(object id)
        {
            return _repository.GetById(id);
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _repository.Find(predicate);
        }

        public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            _repository.Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            _repository.Update(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Remove(TEntity entity)
        {
            _repository.Remove(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
            _repository.Dispose();
        } 
    }
}
```

**Camada de Aplicacao**

```
namespace Sistema.Application.ViewModels
{
    public class PaisViewModel
    {
        public int PaisId { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Sistema.Application.Interfaces
{
    public interface IPaisAppService : IDisposable
    {
        IEnumerable<PaisViewModel> GetAll();
        PaisViewModel GetById(object id);
        IEnumerable<PaisViewModel> Find(Expression<Func<PaisViewModel, bool>> predicate);
        void Add(PaisViewModel paisViewModel);
        void Update(PaisViewModel paisViewModel);
        void Remove(PaisViewModel paisViewModel);  
    }
}


namespace Sistema.Application
{
    public class PaisAppService : AppServiceBase<SistemaContext>, IPaisAppService
    {

        private readonly IPaisService _paisService;

        public PaisAppService(IPaisService cidadeService)
        {
            _paisService = cidadeService;
        }

        public IEnumerable<PaisViewModel> GetAll()
        {
            return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Pais>, IEnumerable<PaisViewModel>>(_paisService.GetAll());
        }

        public PaisViewModel GetById(object id)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<Pais, PaisViewModel>(_paisService.GetById(id));
        }

        public IEnumerable<PaisViewModel> Find(Expression<Func<PaisViewModel, bool>> predicate)
        {
            // Não estou conseguindo implementar
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Add(PaisViewModel paisViewModel)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Update(PaisViewModel paisViewModel)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Remove(PaisViewModel paisViewModel)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}



    public IEnumerable<PaisViewModel> Find(Expression<Func<PaisViewModel, bool>> predicate)
    {
        // Não estou conseguindo implementar
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: movi a sua edição pra a sua pergunta, é nela que a edição deve ficar. Vou analisar o código.

Comment: Olha, no projeto desse tutorial não tem o `Find`. Você implementou ele por fora? Poderia adicionar a implementação do `Find` do RepositoryBase?

Comment: A pessoal que me passou este projeto já passou desta maneira, minha função seria apenas implementar. Vou analisar.

Comment: Mostra como tá o Find() no `RepositoryBase` que te ajudo.

Comment: public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return DbSet.Where(predicate);
        }

Comment: Vê a edição da minha resposta, isso se deu pq você está utilizando o `Expression<Func<PaisViewModel,bool>>` sendo que o Find do `PaisService` está esperando um `Expression<Func<Pais,bool>>`

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda foi isso mesmo. Funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso de fazer AutoMapper com expression, você tem que utilizar o `.Where()` e não o `.Find()`.

O `.Find()` retorna um único elemento e você está tentando fazer o map pra uma collection.

Ficaria assim:

```
public IEnumerable<PaisViewModel> Find(Expression<Func<PaisViewModel, bool>> predicate)
{
   return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Pais>, IEnumerable<PaisViewModel>>(_paisService.Where(predicate));
}
```

Ou

```
public PaisViewModel Find(Expression<Func<PaisViewModel, bool>> predicate)
{
   return Mapper.Map<Pais, PaisViewModel>(_paisService.Find(predicate));
}
```

---

**Edit**

Aparentemente o motivo do erro é que você está utilizando:

```
Expression<Func<PaisViewModel,bool>>
```

Quando na verdade deveria utilizar:

```
Expression<Func<Pais,bool>>
```

Comment: Meu metodo retorna um IEnumerable neste caso acontece o seguinte erro. Teria que mudar meus métodos para retorna um IQueryble?

Comment: Error 1 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'Sistema.Domain.Interfaces.Services.IPaisService' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Sistema.Application.ViewModels.PaisViewModel>' C:\..\Sistema\src\Sistema.Application\PaisAppService.cs 58 78 Sistema.Application

Comment: Error 2 'Sistema.Domain.Interfaces.Services.IPaisService' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments C:\..\Sistema\src\Sistema.Application\PaisAppService.cs 58 78 Sistema.Application

Comment: Essas são Minhas Interfaces

Comment: IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
        TEntity GetById(object id);
        IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
         void Add(TEntity entity);
        void Update(TEntity entity);
        void Remove(TEntity entity);

Comment: @Gilmar, essas interfaces são do seu service? Poderia mostrar como está implementado o Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>)?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer o mapper do predicado:

```
var newPredicate = Mapper.Map<Expression<Func<Class, bool>>>
```

**Exemplo:**

```
public IEnumerable<PaisViewModel> Search(Expression<Func<PaisViewModel, bool>> predicate)
{
var newPredicate = Mapper.Map<Expression<Func<Pais, bool>>>(predicate);
return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PaisViewModel>>(_paisService.Search(newPredicate));
}
```